# all_image_infos by pid on OS X c++

Tags: c++, macos, exc-bad-access

I am currently trying to obtain the base addresses from an external process
using C++ in Xcode!
This is what I got so far:

```
 if (task_info(this->_pmach_port, TASK_DYLD_INFO, (task_info_t)&dyld_info, &count) == KERN_SUCCESS)
 {
     this->Read(this->dyld_info.all_image_info_addr, sizeof(dyld_all_image_infos), &this->all_image_infos);
     printf("Got Task info!\nall_image offset: 0x%llx\ninfo array count: %i",this->dyld_info.all_image_info_addr,this->all_image_infos.infoArrayCount);
     printf("Version: %i\n",this->all_image_infos.version);

     for(int i=0;i< this->all_image_infos.infoArrayCount;i++) {
         printf("image: %s %d\n",
                this->all_image_infos.infoArray[i].imageFilePath,
                this->all_image_infos.infoArray[i].imageLoadAddress
                );
      }
 }
```

There is no problem and my output is the following:

```
    Process To open: hl2_osx   
    Got Task info!
    all_image offset: 0x8feb052c
    info array count: 303 Version: 14
```

My main problem is that Xcode stops at the line where I want to output my module infos
with reason:

> EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=EXC_I368_GPFLT)

What I am doing wrong?

Since I just switched from using the WINApi functions on windows to write programs on an mac,

I hope someone can help me!

Comment: I think that `imageFilePath` is not a null-terminated string.

Comment: @pqnet but, my infoArray is also empty..

Answer (score 1):

For any pointer in the struct, you can't directly access the pointed-to data. You have to read it from the other process, just like you read the `all_image_infos` struct. The `info_array` pointer has that issue. So does the `imageFilePath` that is within it. Etc.

---

```
struct dyld_image_info *infoArray;
size_t size = sizeof(*infoArray) * this->all_image_infos.infoArrayCount;
infoArray = malloc(size);
this->Read(this->all_image_infos.infoArray, size, infoArray);
for(int i=0;i< this->all_image_infos.infoArrayCount;i++) {
    char path[PATH_MAX];
    this->Read(infoArray[i].imageFilePath, sizeof(path), path);
    path[sizeof(path) - 1] = 0;
    // Alternatively, you could use memchr() to see if path is null-terminated. If not, print what you have and read more, in a loop.
    printf("image: %s %d\n",
           path,
           infoArray[i].imageLoadAddress
           );
}
```

Comment: yeah , so i need to read it like the all_image_infos struct. 
but HOW ?
 whats my offset to the info array?
 i am confused..

Comment: Check my updated answer. Basically, any "pointer" in the struct copied from the other process is just an "address" for reading from that process.

Comment: well, thank you for your answer!
anyway this isn't working like it should. since i need to get
the module names and there base adresses, my output is a bit creepy.
well, this is how it looks like : 
        image: \330\345\303_\377 0
        image: \330\345\303_\377 0
        image: \330\345\303_\377 0
        image: \330\345\303_\377 0
        image: \330\345\303_\377 0
        image: \330\345\303_\377 0
        image: \330\345\303_\377 0

Comment: The junk is the same each time. Are you sure your `Read()` function is working properly? Did you try logging `this->all_image_infos.infoArray` to see if it was reasonable. As noted in the comment in `<mach-o/dyld_images.h>`, it may be `NULL` if you obtain it while dyld is manipulating it in the other process.

Comment: @KenThomases Sorry for the necro. I'm trying to read in the infoArray using vm_read but i'm always getting a null array. I get the pointer address from all_image_infos->infoArray but when reading it using vm_read I'm always getting a Null Response

Comment: @mattvv What is the return code from `vm_read()`? Perhaps you should post a new question where you can show the details of how you're calling it and what the exact results are.